# apollo client:codegen typescript with @client query fields

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo

Sorry if this is a bit involved, but I'm really trying to close the
last mile on being able to use Apollo Client for local as well as
server state, with automatic Typescript everywhere. To wit, I have a query like this:

```
query NavigationBarQuery($userId: Int, $portfolioCompanyId: Int!) {
  user(id: $userId) {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    company {
      ... on CompanyInterface {
        companyType
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That is being imported by my NavigationBar component like so:

```
import { NavigationBarQuery, NavigationBarQueryVariables } from '../../../graphql/generated/NavigationBarQuery';
import NAVIGATION_BAR_QUERY from '../../../graphql/NavigationBarQuery.graphql';

const NavigationBar = (vars: NavigationBarQueryVariables) => (
  <Query query={NAVIGATION_BAR_QUERY} variables={vars}>
    {({ loading, error, data, client }: QueryResult<INavigationBarClientQuery>) => {

     // etc.
```

Generation is performed with a local schema file (dumped from Graphene) like so:

```
apollo client:codegen --localSchemaFile ./build/schema.json --includes './src/graphql/**' --target typescript
```

This works great, I get TypeScript types and everything.

However, I'd like to include some local state, with a query like this:

```
query NavigationBarQuery($userId: Int, $portfolioCompanyId: Int!) {
  user(id: $userId) {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    company {
      ... on CompanyInterface {
        companyType
      }
    }
  }
  showNavbarUserInfo @client
}
```

This query *works* just fine if I bypass TypeScript, but when I
attempt to generate Typescript definitions for it, the generation
script emits this error:

```
.../client/src/graphql/NavigationBarQuery.graphql: Cannot query field "showNavbarUserInfo" on type "Query".
{ ToolError: Validation of GraphQL query document failed
    at Object.validateQueryDocument (/Users/gavin/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/apollo-language-server/lib/errors/validation.js:32:19)
    at Object.generate [as default] (/Users/gavin/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/apollo/lib/generate.js:19:18)
    at write (/Users/gavin/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:64:54)
    at Task.task (/Users/gavin/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/apollo/lib/commands/client/codegen.js:83:46) name: 'ToolError' }
```

What, if anything, is the workaround for this? As per usual, looking for examples.

Comment: Gavin, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: cnp's answer below worked

Answer (score 15):

I just worked through this so hopefully this will help someone. And if your name actually is "Someone" and you just happen to be looking for this information; this IS totally for you!

### My setup:

I have two schema files.

- One that is pulled down form my GraphQL Server
- A local schema file that contains the extended properties for storing values locally

### Dependencies

- `@apollo/client": "^3.3.11"`
- `@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0"`

## DevDependencies

- `@graphql-codegen/add": "^2.0.2"`
- `@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.20.1"`
- `@graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-client-helpers": "^1.1.2"`
- `@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.14"`
- `@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.1"`

1. For better usage, I recommend creating a `codegen.yml` file (unless you've watched a lot of hacker movies and think it's WAY more cool to use the console for all these options. Or, if you just want to... I'm not judging.)

```yaml
#./codegen.yml
# See: https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/codegen-config
overwrite: true
schema:
  - "https://my-dev-server.com/v1/graphql":
      headers:
        'Authorization': 'Bearer [TOKEN]'
generates:
  graphql/generated/generated.ts:
    # This is the defined client side schema file. It will first load the root schema defined above, and then load this (see: https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/schema-field#local-graphql-files)
    schema: graphql/client-schema.graphql
    # This is where the gql queries/subscripts/mutations reside
    documents: "graphql/queries/**/*.ts"
    plugins:
      - add:
          content: /* eslint-disable */
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-react-apollo
    config:
      withHooks: true
```

2. Setup local schema file. Call it what you like, just make sure you set the value correctly in the `codegen.yml`. I've called mine `client-schema.graphql` since I'm super clever....

```yaml
#./client-schema.graphql

# see: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/
directive @client on FIELD

type LocalStateType {
  companyId: String
  contactId: String
}

extend type Users {
  localState: LocalStateType!
}
```

3. Once the above is in place and depending on your IDE, intellisense should start picking up the changes. You will need to use the `@client` directive on your query(s); like so:

```
export const QUERY_USER_BY_ID = gql`
  query getUserDetails($Id: uuid!) {
    Users_by_pk(Id: $Id) {
      EmailAddress
      Id
      localState @client {
        companyId
        contactId
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

4. Run the command to generate the goods:

- `npx graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml`

### KEY NOTES

- I've noticed that there is no errors displayed if you set the path incorrectly for the client (`client-schema.graphql`) file. However, you'll know you have it wrong if you don't see the generated data in the output referencing the @client data.

## References:

- https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/codegen-config
- https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/schema-field#local-graphql-files
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies/

Comment: `directive @client on FIELD` is a nice one that I wouldn't have known about without your answer.

Comment: Also works with `graphql-let`. Only difference is point to the `client-schema.graphql` in `graphql-let.yml` vs `codegen.yml`.

Comment: @anAgent Thank you so much. Spent hours on this and your solution finally solves my problem

Comment: Brilliant! And funny, so you get two votes (don't ask how).

Answer (score 8):

Providing an updated answer here because @cnp's answer is missing examples and contains broken links.

My examples use the new Apollo CLI (https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) with `npx`, although it can also be installed locally and used without the `npx` command.

You need to extend your schema with local-only fields by adding a new SDL file. Using the example queries from the original question, you would add a file (e.g. `schema.graphql`) with the following content:

```
extend type NavigationBar {
  showNavbarUserInfo: Boolean!
}
```

**Optional:** if you're using VS Code's Apollo GraphQL extension, now would be a good time to let it know where to find the new SDL file by adding it to the `includes` properly in `apollo.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    includes: ['./schema.graphql'],
  },
};
```

Now include the `showNavbarUserInfo @client` local field in one of your queries, then run your code gen command to include your original `schema.json` file and your new `schema.graphql` file:

```
npx apollo codegen:generate --localSchemaFile=schema.json,schema.graphql --target=typescript --includes=src/**/*.tsx --tagName=gql --addTypename --globalTypesFile=src/types/global-types.ts types
```

Comment: Note to future readers... the new recommended codegen is here: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you need to define a `.graphql` SDL file with your client local state types. The codegen feature will then see this file and merge it in with your main schema. See https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/949#issuecomment-459907307 for more info, and this link for an example: https://github.com/apollographql/fullstack-tutorial/blob/master/final/client/src/resolvers.js#L4. Note the use of `extends Query`.

Comment: could you please update the answer? the links are not there, so it would be really great if we could have new examples.

Comment: @Mr.Ghamkhar I provided an updated answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65458857/188740